# Limit zoom page

Tags: javascript, html

Using Firefox, a user can enlarge an entire web page by simply pressing <kbd>CTRL +</kbd>.

I want to prevent users from zooming in more than 150%. How can I go about doing this? I tried googling, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? zooming is a very good accessibility tool for visual-impaired people, why would you want to break that ?

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers. That said, I would discourage you from preventing zooming above 150%. Even if higher zooms break your page layout and design, is it really worth taking that option away from users (who, if they're zooming in that much, likely have vision difficulties)?

Comment: Firefox changed from text-only to full page zoom several major versions ago. Now it's difficult to get a broken layout because of that. He must have another reason.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario If you have enough elements with `position: fixed`, it's still possible to get a broken layout.